# MATCH AGAINST across multiple tables without joins

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I'm trying to use fulltext and match against multiple tables but without `Join` because they are not related.
I've tried something like:

```
SELECT mg_users.username, mg_users.email, mg_uzgajivac.imeuzgajivaca ...
  FROM mg_users,mg_uzgajivac,mg_buy_it_now,mg_golu ...
 WHERE MATCH(mg_users.username) AGAINST ('rasa')
    OR MATCH(mg_users.email) AGAINST ('rasa')
    OR MATCH(mg_uzgajivac.imeuzgajivaca) AGAINST ('rasa')
    OR MATCH(mg_uzgajivac.mjesto) AGAINST ('rasa') ...
```

But it returns nothing, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried sub queries?

Comment: yes, it works with simple query, but when I add more tables it wont' return anything

Comment: can you try a different username? I am wonder if rasa is a key that is eliminated

Comment: everything is there, it exists in database

Comment: @DarioTrboviæ  the query looks okay. Are you using Innodb tables? what version of MySQL are you using? can you check what the output of `show global variables like "ft_min_word_len"` AND `show global variables like "innodb_ft_min_token_size"` returns?

Comment: It doesn't work with longer words either. I'm not sure if my query with MATCH AGAINST is correct, is it correct way of writing that query. Mysql 5.6

Comment: Can you please show your entire query? also, can you answer the question the I asked previously?

Comment: entire query is very big. ft_min_word_len is 4 and innodb_ft_min_token_size is 3

Comment: Maybe I should use UNION between tables that are not related?

Comment: Can you try the query only with `WHERE MATCH(mg_users.username) AGAINST ('rasa')`

Comment: It works with simple query but it doesn't work with complicated query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that the indexes are not up to date. You need to rebuild your indexes for MATCH ... AGAINST to work correctly.

If you are using MyISAM tables then repair the tables will rebuild you the indexes

```
REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

But if you are using Innodb tables "and you should." You can execute a fake ALTER command which will force the indexes to be rebuild. It will not change anything but it will force the table to rebuild.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=innodb;
```

This may be off-topic but it is something to think about. You can use a multiple column fulltext index to make your query a bit faster

ALTER TABLE mg_users ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (user_name, email);
ALTER TABLE mg_uzgajivac ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (imeuzgajivaca, mjesto);

Then your query will look like this

```
SELECT mg_users.username, mg_users.email, mg_uzgajivac.imeuzgajivaca ...
FROM mg_users,mg_uzgajivac,mg_buy_it_now,mg_golu ...
WHERE MATCH(mg_users.username, mg_users.email) AGAINST ('rasa')
    OR MATCH(mg_uzgajivac.imeuzgajivaca, mg_uzgajivac.mjesto) AGAINST ('rasa')
    ...
```